# Trigger an Email when text changes in formatted cell?

Tags: triggers, formatting, sendmail, conditional-formatting

I've been tasked with setting up a GoogleSheet that contains information about my team's software and the expiry date of their licenses. I have set up the Sheet so when it reaches an expiry date it changes a column to read "Expired".

What I'd like to happen is that when the cell text changes to "Expired" it send me an email to alert me.
I found some tips online and tried a script but can't seem to get it to function as expected.

Here's what my Google Sheet looks like:

[image: google sheet with team licenses]

Here's the code i've been trying to adapt:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 6 || e.value != "Expired") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,5).getValues();
  let lictyp = rData[0][2];
  let swpi = rData[0][1];
  let name = rData[0][0];
  
  let msg = "The " + lictyp + "license for " + swpi + "will expire in 10 days time for " + name + "." + "Contact IT to renew licence asap. Kind Regards, LICENSE NINJA!";
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@address.com", "License Expiry Alert", msg)
}
```

Comment: When you say it’s not working as expected, can you clarify what the actual behavior is?

Comment: About `when the cell text changes to "Expired"`, in your situation, what is that changed by? For example, the cell value is manually changed or by a script?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I've set up a panel on the far right that contains today's date. I've set up some conditional formatting on the cells that are driven by today's date & the license expiry date. So if a license will expire in over ten days, the Status will say "OK". If the license will expire in less than ten days, the Status will say "Expires Soon". If the license is on or past its expiry date, the Status will read "Expired". What I'm hoping to achieve is that when the Status changes to "Expires Soon" an email will be triggered to alert me that a license needs attention

Comment: hi @Tanaike, the text is changed by some script that, based on today's date, detects how many days before or past the expiry date of the license is. If the license expires in over 10 days the text should read "OK", if the license expires in 10 days or less the text should read "Expires Soon". If the license is on or past the expire date the text should read "Expired". I want the email to be triggered when the text changes to "Expires Soon" to alert me something needs addressing.

Comment: hi @Tanaike, no problem. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I'll try to explain it simply. The text in the Status column is changed by some script that changes depending on the license's expiry date. What I would like to happen is when the text changes to "Expires Soon" this triggers an email that is sent to me. The text changes dynamically, not manually. Hope that helps.